# Any uses of Hydra Core Vocabulary?

Tags: api, json

[JSON-LD](http://json-ld.org/index.html) starts having a fairly large number of users. [Hydra](http://www.hydra-cg.com/) is a lightweight vocabulary to create hypermedia-driven Web APIs. Are there any significant sites or project that use Hydra with JSON-LD?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you mean Hydra-based Web APIs that closely resemble current JSON-based APIs, than I guess the answer is that no "significant site or project" has published anything production ready yet. Quite of a few people and a handful of startups mentioned that they are working on it. If, on the other hand, you include [Triple Pattern Fragment servers](http://www.hydra-cg.com/spec/latest/triple-pattern-fragments/), which are based on the Hydra Core vocabulary, then there are actually quite a few significant projects that serve their data using Hydra. There's even a post claiming there are [more than 600,000 of them](http://lists.w3.org/Archives/Public/public-hydra/2015Jan/0227.html) :-) You can also find a short list of prominent projects on http://linkeddatafragments.org/data/.

*Disclaimer: I'm the chair of the Hydra W3C Community Group and one of the core designers of JSON-LD.*